# Canvas object Tags: not the type I originally gave it

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a canvas that I add various objects to, such as text objects, etc.  I add "tag" properties to each canvas child object.  In the example below, I add a dict for the "tag" property which is absolutely supported:

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
myCanvas = tkinter.Canvas( window, width = 400, height = 400 )
myCanvas.pack()

textItemTags = { "id": 1, "name": "test" }
textItemContents = "asdf"
textItem = myCanvas.create_text( 1, 1, tags = textItemTags, text = textItemContents )

# some method later on now tries to retrieve tag values for a selected canvas child object...
searchTags = myCanvas.gettags( textItem )

print( searchTags ) # array of strings
print( isinstance( searchTags[0], str ) ) # true..?
```

Problem: note return results for `searchTags` using `gettags` method of the canvas object - this is an array of strings now representing each line item ("'id': 1, 'name': 'test'", "..." ), not an actual dict as was originally passed in.

My questions are: 1) why is this an array of strings now and not the original dict (or at least clone) that I passed in; and 2) What infallible way can I parse this string array to rebuild exactly what I originally passed in to the `create_text` method?

Disclaimer: relatively new to Python and tkinter, but the results of retrieving tag values for canvas child objects seems odd to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Tk canvas documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M17):

> Each item may also have any number of tags associated with it. A tag
> is just a string of characters, ***and it may take any form except that
> of an integer.*** For example, `x123` is OK but `123` isn't…

And according to Tkinter [`Canvas.create_text`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201105231837id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method)  documentation:

> `tags=`
>
> **A tag** to attach to this item, or **a tuple** containing multiple tags.

Also in the same [An Introduction to Tkinter](https://web.archive.org/web/20201105231837id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/), the [The Tkinter Canvas Widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) section says:

> **Tags** are symbolic names attached to items. Tags are ordinary strings, and they can contain anything except whitespace (***as long as they don’t look like item handles***).

(Italic emphasis mine.)

It seems like Tkinter/Tk converts the `tags` parameter to a string if it is not a string nor a tuple.

---

How about using a dictionary to map tag name to the dictionary:

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
myCanvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width = 400, height = 400)
myCanvas.pack()

tag_mapping = {}                                      # <----
tag_mapping['tag1'] = { "id": 1, "name": "test" }     # <----
textItemContents = "asdf"
textItem = myCanvas.create_text(1, 1, tags='tag1', text = textItemContents)

searchTags = myCanvas.gettags(textItem)

print(searchTags) # => ('tag1',)
print(searchTags[0]) # => tag1
print(tag_mapping[searchTags[0]]) # => {'name': 'test', 'id': 1}
print(isinstance(tag_mapping[searchTags[0]], dict)) # => True
```

Comment: thanks.  Documentation for tkinter is hard to come by so I'll save your link.  "A tag is just a string" and "A tag to attach to this item, or a tuple containing multiple tags" makes sense now.

Comment: "and it may take any form except that of an integer."  Just noticed this part.  I just did assign a numeric string tag and read it back fine.  Example: str "1".  What do I have to fear by doing this?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer, You don't need to worry about it as long as the tag is `str`.

Comment: cool, N/m.  Just checking if I should take it literally that numeric strings were not allowed and if this would present some sort of gotcha later on.  From testing numeric strings, there was no immediate problem at all.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer: you can't use numeric strings because they will be interpreted differently. When you create an item on the canvas it is given an ID, this ID is a numeric string. If you have tags that are numeric strings, tkinter won't know if "12" represents a tag or the numeric ID "12". It will always assume it means the numeric ID.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: thanks. That's what I was apprehensive about.  That makes the `tagOrId` often referenced in documentation sites like effbot.org and infohost.nmt.edu more understandable.  That reinforces falsetru's solution of using an intermediary map.