# tkinter canvas can't seem to create a tag within a function

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tags

Making a basic game using tkinter only. I can use a tag in my main program fine, but when I create one in my function I'm ignored. Below is the problem part of the code. The alienship tag works fine. The tag is saved and is usable. But for the line create inside the function, no matter how I assign the tag, it isn't saved. I've tried tag/tags/string instead of a variable/itemconfig/using bob=/master.bob=

I'm out of ideas.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=600, height=800,bg='black')
w. pack()

bang = 0        #check if there's a shot active
shottag = "1"
alientag = "a"

def control(event):
    global bang,shottag

    key = event.keycode
    if key == 38:                 #up arrow
        if bang<3:
            bang=bang+1
            shottag=shottag+"1"
            xy = w.coords(ship)
            w.create_line(xy[0],700,xy[0],730,fill="white",width=3,tag=shottag)
          # w.coords(shottag) would produce [] here -- i.e. no coords

shippic = PhotoImage(file = "ship.gif")
ship = w.create_image(300, 750, anchor=CENTER, image=shippic)

aliens = PhotoImage(file = "head.gif")
w.create_image(random.randint(40,560), 40, anchor=CENTER, image=aliens, tag=alientag)
  
w.after(100,moveals,alientag)
# this tag works fine

master.bind('<Key>',control)
```

Comment: Don't worry if it is a 'dumb' question. We are all here to learn.

Comment: What makes you think the tag isn't being created?

Comment: I know that tag isn't being created because when the cords() command doesn't see it, nor does the .find_withtag(), nor does gettags()

And I know it has nothing to do with returns, because the tag isn't seen within the function right after I create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a tag which has only numbers so it looks like "**item handle**" so it's not treated as tag.

Use char in tag - ie. `shottag = "s"` - and it will work.

---

From effbot.org [The Tkinter Canvas Widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm):

> **Tags** are symbolic names attached to items. Tags are ordinary strings, and they can contain anything except whitespace (**as long as they don’t look like item handles**).

Comment: Thanks. I'd been on that site and missed that bit of info. It is working.

Comment: @user7278007: Tags are just ordinary strings, but there are [several rules regarding their format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21807958/355230) that must be followed.

Answer (score 0):

With variables used inside of a function, you have to return them. For example:

```
a = 5
b = 6
def func(a,b):
    a += 5
    b += 5
    return a
a = func(a,b)
print(a) #10
print(b) #6, not 11
```

It doesn't change the variable inside the function, so you must return the variable and reassign it, like I did with `a`. `b` won't change unless you reassign it to the function value.

If you need to return multiple values:

```
return [a, b]
f = func(a, b)
a, b = f[0], f[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, but if the tag doesn't exist in the line right after I create it (inside the function) then a return won't help.

Nice simple example though :)